# Control theory implemented in C++

Tags: android, c++, control-theory, pid-controller

I am doing Android programming using Java-Eclipse Luna on Windows 8.1, also, I am using native environment (C++). As a next step in my project, I have to control a mobile robot by building an app in Android.

My question is, are there any already-implemented control theory libraries in C++ that I just import and use in my C++ code? I need PID, LQR, LQG ... etc.

Answer (score 2):

Check out ROS (Robot Operating System), it contains plenty of algorithms and useful tools for robotic applications.

Comment: ROS only contains a PID controller, not LQR, LQG or even lowpass/highpass/bandpass filters.